# Team based project management software using .NET

Tags: .net, project-management

Does anyone know any team based project management software for a small programming team of 5 that uses .NET, has good SCM integration and can all be hosted in-house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS Express gives all the power of Team Foundation Server for up to 5 users. I like TFS - it's not perfect by any means, but it extremely powerful and I've seen it used effectively on teams as small as 3 and as large as 60.

It's got nice web interfaces for Agile / Scrum type projects and traditional waterfall.

- Native Visual Studio integration
- Continuous build & integration
- Integrated work management, easy to correlate project management artifacts from request to requirements through development, test and deployment.
- Good integration with Microsoft Project and Excel for more robust PM activities and portfolio management
- Really good release management in the newest version

Answer (score 0):

[Fluxes](https://fluxes.com/) is an extremely powerful web based team collaboration tool that allows larger teams manage projects effectively without paying a penny. I like the simplicity of the tool. Although I am not sure if it will meet all of your requirements.